# how to change UI based on orientation but at the same avoid activity restart when orientation change

Tags: android, layout, android-orientation, android-configchanges

HI I am new to android application development.I know android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" is used to avoid activity Restart but it does not allow UI(layout-port,layout-land) changes too.But What i want is,

I need to avoid activity restart when orientation changes and also take an effect of UI changes.(i.e) if the mobile in portrait the layout takes from layout-port (or) if the mobile in landscape the layout takes from layout-land

Is this possible to achive?If yes means reply soon.
If any body know this Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just let the Activity restart and handle configuration changes as the system intends. It's not that difficult to save state.

Comment: Can't have your cake and eat it too. That's the tradeoff you make when you handle configuration changes yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try to call `setContentView(R.layout.sample)` again at `onConfigurationChanged` Method.

Comment: I already tried Ali, But it does not allow user to interact with UI again

Comment: You have to write a common method to get all the resources using their ID's and call that method from onCreate and onConfigChange.

Comment: Ya Ali i did like that only..but no use for that..Is there any alternative way other than this alki...thanks for spending time for me ali

Comment: If you are doing like this only than user can interact with UI. May be you are doing something wrong please check your code once.